# Short circuit while measuring

Tags: oscilloscope, short-circuit

I wanted to measure a LVDS signal across the termination resistor with my oscilloscope. I tried to measure it with DC coupling and AC coupling. Using the AC coupling option led to a short circuit I saw some sparks.

Why did the AC coupling option led to a short circuit?

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that the "sparks" had anything to do with the coupling selections.

Rather, the most likely case is that you connected the scope's ground to the circuit, but the point at which you connected did not match the (likely mains) ground of the scope.  This could suggest either that you don't sufficiently understand the design of the system you are examining to safely performance measurements on it, or that there are issues with the mains wiring in the area where you are working.